# enum not working with C++ using mingw compiler on Windows7

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, mingw

I am trying to compile libaws on Windows using mingw compiler. Inside the libaws (https://sourceforge.net/projects/libaws/) code, I try this:

```
C:/la/include/libaws/config.h:2:0: warning: "WIN32" redefined [enabled by default]
<built-in>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/canonizer.h:23:0,
                    from C:\tools\libaws-0.9.2\src\s3\s3connection.cpp:25:
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:62:9: error: expected identifier before '(' token
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:62:9: error: expected '}' before '(' token
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:62:9: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:62:9: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:70:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:109:19: error: 'ActionType' was not declared in this scope
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:109:43: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:110:19: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:110:51: error: expected primary-expression before 'aExpiration'
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:129:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'private'
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:135:51: error: 'ActionType' has not been declared
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:139:40: error: variable or field 'setRequestMethod' declared void
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:139:40: error: 'ActionType' was not declared in this scope
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:154:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:161:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:143:7: warning: 'size_t aws::s3::getS3Data(void*, size_t, size_t, void*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Wunused-function]
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:146:7: warning: 'size_t aws::s3::setCreateBucketData(void*, size_t, size_t, void*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Wunused-function]
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:149:7: warning: 'size_t aws::s3::setPutData(void*, size_t, size_t, void*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Wunused-function]
                    C:/tools/libaws-0.9.2/src/s3/s3connection.h:152:7: warning: 'size_t aws::s3::getHeaderData(void*, size_t, size_t, void*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Wunused-function]
                    src\CMakeFiles\aws.dir\build.make:561: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/s3/s3connection.cpp.obj' failed
                    mingw32-make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/s3/s3connection.cpp.obj] Error 1
                    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1006: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/all' failed
                    mingw32-make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/all] Error 2
                    Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed
                    mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

                    C:\la>
```

The place where it is happening is in a class

```
class S3Connection {
    enum ActionType {
        // VALUES
    };
};
```

Comment: In future questions that refer to specific errors in specific files from open source libraries, let us know if some modifications had been made to the library sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one of the enum names in `s3connection.h` conflicts with a macro name in the Win32 SDK.  In Win32, `DELETE` is a macro used for dealing with ACLs (access control lists).  Probably the best way to deal with this is to have:

```
#undef DELETE
```

somewhere after the Windows headers are included and before the the `libaws` headers are included.

Either that, or modify the enum names (and anywhere they might be used) so there's no conflict.

Keep in mind that this is an indication that `libaws` probably hasn't had much use/testing directly on a Windows target, so you might have to pay more in terms of being a pioneer.  You might have better luck using Cygwin instead of MinGW, since it looks like `libaws` has had at least some work done on the Cygwin platform.

Comment: But will cygwin allow me to generate libraries that be used for visual studio? I thought it is like a Unix file system?

Comment: Cygwin programs do rely on the cygwin DLL to provide POSIX emulation/support.  I don't actually use Cygwin, so I'm not sure if it can produce libraries that VS can use.  I'd bet you might be right though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're obviously redefining `WIN32` inside your `enum`. `WIN32` is predefined on Windows platforms.

**Edit:**
There are actually 2 errors in your log:

`WIN32` redefinition in `config.h`, the library actually guides you how to do the per-platform configuration:

```
// unset WIN32 for cygwin environment
#cmakedefine CYGWIN
#ifdef CYGWIN
#  undef WIN32
#endif
```

The second issue is pointed out in @MichaelBurr answer.

Comment: But will cygwin allow me to generate libraries that be used for visual studio? I thought it is like a Unix file system?

Comment: Cygwin is a UNIX emulator inside Windows. I suppose if running inside it, the compiler will generate UNIX binaries.